# Web API method with parameters not working in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have the following API method:

```
[HttpGet]
public List<ListOfUsersModel> GetRegisteredUsers(int courseId)
{
    List<AccountCourse> GetUsers= new AdminBL().GetAccountIdByCourseId(courseId);
    var ListOfUsers = new List<ListOfUsersModel>();

    foreach (AccountCourse a in GetUsers)
    {
        ListOfUsersModel lum = new ListOfUsersModel();
        lum.user = a.AccountId.ToString();
        ListOfUsers.Add(lum);

    }
    return ListOfUsers;
}
```

If I modify the method to "GetRegisteredUsers()" instead, it works perfectly fine. However, if I want to specify a parameter I get the following message: No action was found on the controller 'ThirdParty' that matches the request."}

In global, I have this:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{courseId}",
        defaults: new
         {
             courseId = RouteParameter.Optional
         }
);
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here, any help? Thanks

Comment: What URL are you expecting to match the route?

Comment: http://localhost:54010/api/ThirdParty/GetRegisteredUsers/1 where 1 represents the course id.

Comment: Share code where you're invoking webapi

Comment: Not sure what version you are working with, have you tried forcing a route via attributes? [Route("")]

Comment: It works fine on my machine. Can you share your WebApiConfig.cs and Global.asax files?